WEBVIEW android app cannot download file via server
package com.example.mywebsite;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.webkit.PermissionRequest;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.SslErrorHandler;
import android.net.http.SslError;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.DownloadListener;
import android.webkit.URLUtil;
import android.webkit.WebResourceResponse;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView myWeb;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 1;
    private static final int FILE_CHOOSER_REQUEST_CODE = 2;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Request permissions
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            }, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS);
        }

        // Initialize the WebView
        myWeb = findViewById(R.id.myWeb);
        myWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // Enable JavaScript
        myWeb.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true); // Allow file access for uploads
        myWeb.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true); // Enable DOM storage
        myWeb.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false); // Allow media playback without user gesture

        // Handle SSL errors
        myWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                handler.proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
            }

            @Override
            public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                String url = request.getUrl().toString();
                if (url.endsWith(".pdf") || url.endsWith(".zip") || url.endsWith(".jpg") || url.endsWith(".png") ||
                        url.endsWith(".xlsx") || url.endsWith(".xls") || url.endsWith(".docx") || url.endsWith(".txt") || url.endsWith(".doc") || url.endsWith(".html"))  {
                    // Handle specific file types if needed
                    // For now, just return null to let WebView handle it
                    return null;
                }
                return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request);
            }
        });

        // Handle permission requests for the camera and other resources
        myWeb.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
                request.grant(request.getResources());
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                mFilePathCallback = filePathCallback;
                Intent intent = fileChooserParams.createIntent();
                try {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, FILE_CHOOSER_REQUEST_CODE);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        myWeb.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS);
                } else {
                    startDownload(url, userAgent, contentDisposition, mimetype);
                }
            }
        });

        // Enable WebView debugging
        WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);

        // Load the desired URL
        myWeb.loadUrl("https://************");
    }

    private void startDownload(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype) {
        // Check if running on Android 11 or higher
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            // For Android 11 and above, use MediaStore to save the file
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Downloads.DISPLAY_NAME, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype));
            values.put(MediaStore.Downloads.MIME_TYPE, mimetype);
            values.put(MediaStore.Downloads.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

            Uri downloadUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            request.setMimeType(mimetype);
            request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
            request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
            request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype));
            request.setDestinationUri(downloadUri);

            DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            downloadManager.enqueue(request);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            // For older versions
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            request.setMimeType(mimetype);
            request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
            request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
            request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype));
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype));

            DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            downloadManager.enqueue(request);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS) {
            boolean allPermissionsGranted = true;
            for (int result : grantResults) {
                if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    allPermissionsGranted = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (allPermissionsGranted) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions granted. You can now download files.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions are required to download files.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == FILE_CHOOSER_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (mFilePathCallback == null) return;
            Uri[] results = null;
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (data != null) {
                    results = WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, data);
                }
            }
            mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
            mFilePathCallback = null;
        }
    }
}

This is my AndroidManifest.xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <!-- Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <!-- Conditional storage permissions for Android versions below 11 -->
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="29" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- Notifications permission for Android 13+ -->
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"
        tools:targetApi="33" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <!-- Features -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyWebsite"
        tools:targetApi="31">

        <!-- Main Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Shortcuts Receiver -->
        <receiver
            android:name=".MyShortcutReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.mywebsite.SHORTCUT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- Download Complete Receiver -->
        <receiver
            android:name=".DownloadCompleteReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />
    </application>
</manifest>

here is how download from website works
app.get('/download/:filePath', (req, res) => {
    // Decode the file path
    const decodedPath = decodeURIComponent(req.params.filePath);
    
    // Construct the full path
    const fullPath = path.join('D:\\', decodedPath);

    // Log the full path
    console.log('Attempting to access file at:', fullPath);

    // Check if the file exists and has read permissions
    fs.access(fullPath, fs.constants.R_OK, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('File not found or access error:', err);
            if (!res.headersSent) {
                res.status(404).json({ error: 'File not found' });
            }
            return;
        }

        res.download(fullPath, (downloadErr) => {
            if (downloadErr) {
                if (res.headersSent) {
                    console.error('Error during file download:', downloadErr);
                    return;
                }
                console.error('Error during file download:', downloadErr);
                res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error during file download' });
            } else {
                console.log('File successfully downloaded.');
            }
        });
    });
});


// Helper function to get folder structure
async function getFolderStructure(folderPath) {
    const files = await fs.promises.readdir(folderPath);
    const folderStructure = [];

    for (const file of files) {
        const filePath = path.join(folderPath, file);
        const stats = await fs.promises.stat(filePath);

        if (stats.isDirectory()) {
            folderStructure.push({
                type: 'folder',
                name: file,
                children: await getFolderStructure(filePath) // Recursively get folder structure
            });
        } else {
            folderStructure.push({
                type: 'file',
                name: file
            });
        }
    }

    return folderStructure;
}

I have this web view app it works fine from the browser but from the app i cant download files from the server with some testing i take permissions but again it doesn't start download the test mobile phone has android 13. Feel free to ask for more information about code. My thanks in advance.
